# Rails: Adding an index after adding column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, migration

Suppose I created a table `table` in a Rails app. Some time later, I add a column running:

```
rails generate migration AddUser_idColumnToTable user_id:string.
```

Then I realize I need to add `user_id` as an index. I know about the `add_index` method, but where should this method be called? Am I supposed to run a migration (if yes, which one ?), then adding by hand this method?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

You can run another migration, just for the index:

```
class AddIndexToTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :table, :user_id
  end
end
```

Comment: So I simply run in my console : rails generate migration AddIndexToTable ?

Comment: Yes you can do that, but you will have to edit that migration afterwards to reflect the above code.

Comment: Is :table supposed to be plural?

Comment: @tomb I used the example from the original question. `:table` is the actual table name, so in the case of a `users` table, you'd substitute `:users` for `:table`.

Comment: @tomb yes by rails convention, table names are always plural, so `add_index :bars, :foo` where the table name is `bars`

Answer (score 77):

If you need to create a `user_id` then it would be a reasonable assumption that you are referencing a user table. In which case the migration shall be:

```
rails generate migration AddUserRefToProducts user:references
```

This command will generate the following migration:

```
class AddUserRefToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :user, :product, index: true
  end
end
```

After running `rake db:migrate` both a `user_id` column and an index will be added to the `products` table.

In case you just need to add an index to an existing column, e.g. `name` of a `user` table, the following technique may be helpful:

`rails generate migration AddIndexToUsers name:string:index` will generate the following migration:

```
class AddIndexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :name, :string
    add_index :users, :name
  end
end
```

Delete `add_column` line and run the migration.

In the case described you could have issued `rails generate migration AddIndexIdToTable index_id:integer:index` command and then delete `add_column` line from the generated migration. But I'd rather recommended to undo the initial migration and add reference instead:

```
rails generate migration RemoveUserIdFromProducts user_id:integer
rails generate migration AddUserRefToProducts user:references
```

Comment: Thanks Vadym for the complete answer. One last question: why would you recommend undoing the initial migration? Is there any performance issue related to adding index later on?

Comment: To @fwuensche: there is no performance penalty for adding index later on. The domain logic will be less clear, though. E.g. in case you decide to break/abstract/etc the association later on, you'd need to be dealing with two separate migrations, which really should have been a single one ...

Comment: WARNING: Note that index: true only works in a create_table migration. The migration will run, but no index will be created. See https://makandracards.com/makandra/32353-psa-index-true-in-rails-migrations-does-not-work-as-you-d-expect

Comment: If "Then I realize I need to add user_id as an index" happened after the `user_id` column was already in production, then removing it will delete real data, so that's a bad idea.  If it is still in development, why not just revert and then edit the original migration? Or if you feel the need to leave the original migration code untouched, you could add comments mentioning the relationship between the two migrations.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, could you add how the migration of `rails generate migration RemoveUserIdFromProducts user_id:integer`will look like?

Answer (score 15):

Add in the generated migration after creating the column the following (example)

```
add_index :photographers, :email, :unique => true
```

Comment: you mean something like this : def self.up
    add_column ...
  end  add_index ... ?

Answer (score 15):

For references you can call

```
rails generate migration AddUserIdColumnToTable user:references
```

If in the future you need to add a general index you can launch this

```
rails g migration AddOrdinationNumberToTable ordination_number:integer:index
```

Generated code:

```
class AddOrdinationNumberToTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_column :tables, :ordination_number, :integer
   add_index :tables, :ordination_number, unique: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who are using postgresql db and facing error

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

=== Dangerous operation detected #strong_migrations ===

Adding an index non-concurrently blocks writes
```

please refer [this article](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-create-postgres-indexes-concurrently-in)

example:

```
class AddAncestryToWasteCodes < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def change
    add_column :waste_codes, :ancestry, :string
    add_index :waste_codes, :ancestry, algorithm: :concurrently
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this, just think Job is the name of the model to which you are adding  index **cader_id**:

```
class AddCaderIdToJob < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_table :jobs do |t|
      t.integer :cader_id
      t.index :cader_id
    end
  end
end
```