# How to retrieve user information from database without using numerical indexing in Rails 7?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, optimization, time-complexity, ruby-on-rails-7

Initially, I would use a route like this :

```
www.example.com/users/3
```

with user ID is 3, and then by indexing, we can retrieve user info from DB with O(1) complexity.

But I have changed the route to replace user name instead of Id like so :

```
www.example.com/users/john
```

And now the search complexity is O(n). Is it possible to apply any optimizations here to get O(1)?

Comment: How do you now it's a complexity of O(n)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the :name index is fine, and then update your routes, model, and controller accordingly, and by default know that it will be unique. Making it unique will give you the same query performance as if you were doing a lookup by a primary key (id).

```rb
# migration 
def change
  # not sure why you'd name it user_name as opposed to name
  add_index :users, :name, unique: true
end
```

```rb
# model
class User < ApplicationModel
  validate :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  # ensures path generators use name as param
  def to_param
    name
  end
end
```

```rb
# routes 
resources :user, param: :name
```

```rb
# controller
class UserController
  # if you have a controller method handling the lookup by param, rails adds the find_by_COLUMN method 
  def set_user
    @user = User.find_by_name params[:name]
  end
end
```

Also, to clarify what might sound like the confusion: the migration creates a non-clustered index on Name that stores with it the ID of the corresponding record (user record), like:

```
Name | ID
Bob  | 1
Jil  | 2
```

The name serves as the primary key in this  table, allowing the lookup to be handled by the single param provided in your URL without any numerical data.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass the `user_id`, the query will be

`User.find_by(id: user_id)`

When you pass the `user_name`, the query will be

`User.find_by(user_name: user_name)`

It's not about `rails`, it's about `DB`

You should [add index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881749/rails-adding-an-index-after-adding-column) for `user_name` to optimize

```rb
def change
  add_index :users, :user_name
end
```

Comment: the index will be numerical though, how will I get the index if I'm not passing urls through user id?

Comment: What is the `index`? I'm not clear what you want to get. 
We have user_name as an input, what is the expected result?

Comment: when we add an index to the database it will be numerical 1 to 999.. , but my url doesn't contain any numbers, only letters, how will I use the index if I'm not passing index number?

Comment: You mean the `ID` is `index`, right? You can query `user = User.find_by(user_name: user_name)` and then `user.id`, you will get the `index`

Comment: yeah, but that will be O(n)

Comment: It will be O(1) after adding `index` for the field `user_name`

Comment: If it's a proper RDBMS, you should not think of O(1) or O(n). Just use the the provided tools to analyze your DB Query. Eg. for PostgreSQL it's "explain select * from users where user_name='stefan'   ". And as always in performance analysis: The results will differ between prod and dev

Comment: @JohnSall It might help to review database indexes. [Use The Index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) is a good resource.